# Not allowed to use Joiner transformation

Tags: informatica-powercenter, joiner

I have an expression transformation from which I am passing the data to two different transformations.

Later in the downstream of these parallel flows, I am trying to apply a joiner transformation  but I am not allowed to do so.,

Is joiner transformation not allowed in a such a case similar to self-join?
What could be an alternative approach if I wanted to achieve such a transformation?

It would be great if somebody can help me sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the data before the joiner, and turn on 'sorted merge join' before connecting the second set of ports to the joiner.

One voice of caution though: carefully consider the 'key' you join these data on. I should be a unique value across all records on at least one of the two data streams, otherwise you'll end up with a data explosion. I know this may sound very basic, but it is often forgotten in self joins :)

Answer (score 0):

Joiner Transformation will work. I assume the if the data is from same source table and is passed through different pipe line, use the option of `SORTED INPUT` in the joiner transformation.